Use WC Kalkulator product field values to update WooCommerce cart item product properties
In WooCommerce, I use the WC Kalkulator plugin for a simple product (ID 4692). The problem is, this simple product has only static weight and dimensions values that get pulled into each cart item addition. That makes a 12"x12" sign panel with a weight of 2 lbs cost the same to ship as a panel 120" x 48" at 80 lbs. I have fields setup in WC Kalkulator plugin to define the calculated weight and dimensions.
I have a code started that is intended to use the calculated data to apply to the product's data as it is entered into the cart. Each instance of the cart item should be unique to the inputted values.
I will say that I am not a coder, and I got this far with Copilot AI help:
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'update_custom_price', 10, 1 );
function update_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $product->get_id();

        // Check if the product ID matches the specific product
        if ( $product_id == 4692 ) {
            // Get the custom field value
            $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( 4692, 'wck_weight', true );
            $custom_field_value1 = get_post_meta( 4692, 'wck_length', true );
            $custom_field_value2 = get_post_meta( 4692, 'wck_width', true );
            $custom_field_value3 = get_post_meta( 4692, 'wck_height', true );

            // Update the product weight and dimensions
            $product->set_weight( $custom_field_value );
            $product->set_length( $custom_field_value1 );
            $product->set_width( $custom_field_value2 );
            $product->set_height( $custom_field_value3 );
        }
    }
}

I don't know if the "get_post_meta" is looking in the right spot to find the WCK fields. The fields are correctly named, and the product id is correct for my intentions.

There are some mistakes in your code, as the data is posted as custom cart item data, but there is no related product metadata. Try the following:
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_item_weight_and_dimensions' );
function custom_item_weight_and_dimensions( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( isset($item['wckalkulator_fields']) ) {
            $fields = (array) $item['wckalkulator_fields'];
            if ( isset($fields['wck_weight']) && !empty($fields['wck_weight']) ) {
                $item['data']->set_weight($fields['wck_weight']);
            }

            if ( isset($fields['wck_length']) && !empty($fields['wck_length']) ) {
                $item['data']->set_length($fields['wck_length']);
            }

            if ( isset($fields['wck_width']) && !empty($fields['wck_width']) ) {
                $item['data']->set_width($fields['wck_width']);
            }

            if ( isset($fields['wck_height']) && !empty($fields['wck_height']) ) {
                $item['data']->set_height($fields['wck_height']);
            }
        }
    }
}

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work if you gave the correct field keys in your code attempt.
Note that in my code attempt, there is no need to define a product ID as my code will check if each related custom cart item data exists and has a value, to update the related cart item (product) properties.

The result is still unsuccessful at prompting the UPS live ship to receive updated weights. I double checked the field keys align with the WC Kalkulator. The item's weight and dimensions are not being applied as they are added to the cart.

@Jreppe Sorry but I have tested everything in a test server with WC Kalkulator plugin, using your provided fields keys, and on my side it works perfectly... Of course that the product inputted fields values are added as custom cart item data (that is what the plugin does)...

I think I found the problem. Within the WC Kalkulator, I had calculated values with the "Value of Formula" field. When I used a "Number Field" value, it came right in and worked. I don't know why that makes any difference, but it does. Those value of formula fields were set to show on the cart and everything. Palm to forehead..

Would you happen to have an idea of how to use the calculated "value of formula" fields for this purpose? I wonder if because they are not in the user input fields, that calculated data isn't getting pulled into the lookup? Only thing I can think of is to maybe use the JavaScript function at the bottom of the WC Kalkulator Fieldset plugin, to set min/max values that equal the value of the referenced "value of formula" that doesn't work..

I never used WC Kalkulator plugin before, so I don't know how to use it better than you: Search and ask in the plugin support threads. Your question is not really clear and detailed, it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do and what is the context… Generally, Is better to use pure dedicated custom code instead of a plugin that you don't master and requires additional custom code… Try to improve and update your question, as people can't guess things by magic.

Apologies for my ignorance, coding is not my forte. I'm not sure why, but the field keys for the "value of formula" do not populate as intended. Much along the lines you're suggesting, instead of doing the math from within the plugin, I had it do the required math within the code. It works perfectly now that it's calling for the user defined width and height "number fields" as the variables. Appreciate your help! Popcorn is on the way!! :)

Thanks for the popcorn on the way :) …
